# Replace specific string C#?

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to replace a specific sub string from a string in C#.

My string is: `This is a car.`

And I am trying to replace 'a' with string.Empty from the string with this code:

```
data = data.Replace("a", string.Empty);
```

But my output is :

```
This is c r.
```

I just want to remove isolated occurence of 'a', and not when this char/word is used in some other word (like car).

I want a output like ths: `This is car.`

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Wow, many people who are hot on the triggers :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a regex pattern that only matches "a" on word boundaries. `"\b"` in a regex pattern denotes a word boundary:

```
Regex.Replace("this is a car", @"\ba\b", "")
```

If you want to match uppercase "A" as well, make sure your pattern is ignoring case (`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`) or explicitly add "A" to the pattern like `"\b[Aa]\b"`.

Comment: This will leave two adjacent spaces in the given test case.

Comment: @WizardofOgz It behaves similar to the code written. Of course, that line does not match the output, so I am not sure what exactly is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean with 'isolated occurence'? Is it perhaps something like this you're really after:

```
data.Replace(" a ", " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do couple of different cases but it is certainly possible:

- a in the beginning of the sentence "A car went by"   -> s.StartsWith("A ")
- a in the middle "this is a car"  -> Replace(" a ", " ")

Comment: You forgot the case where the string ends with 'a', required since the string to replace has a trailing whitespace :-)

Comment: This is acceptable solution, but does not seems to be an elegant way of doing it. Is there better way to achieve this?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Arry - What don't you like about Mehrdad Afshari's solution?

Answer (score 1):

search for the spaces too.

```
data = data.(" a ", " ")
```

Comment: someone disagrees with this answer apparently

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of funny to see four people shoot the same one-liner within a couple of seconds, but all of them down-voted at the same time is even more hilarious

Comment: See @Zdravko Danev for the cases your solution does not cover.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex and limit to instances of 'a' that qualify as a word.

```
string input = "This is a car. A thing to watch out for.";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "\ba\b", "");

//Results in "This is car. A thing to watch out for."
```

You can also add a character class to deal with capital and lower case, as well as any other characters. ex. \s[Aa]\s

The \s means any white space character

Comment: Can you please explain this with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Search for the string " a " instead, and replace with a space to keep the sentence construct correct;

```
data = data.Replace(" a ", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

## This seems like a great time to use the replace Method of the StringBuilder class.

> StringBuilder.Replace Method
>
> Replaces all occurrences of a specified character or string in this
> instance with another specified character or string.
>
> OVERLOADS Replace(Char, Char)  Replaces all occurrences of a specified
> character in this instance with another specified character.
>
> Replace(String, String)    Replaces all occurrences of a specified
> string in this instance with another specified string.
>
> Replace(Char, Char, Int32, Int32)  Replaces, within a substring of
> this instance, all occurrences of a specified character with another
> specified character.
>
> Replace(String, String, Int32, Int32)  Replaces, within a substring of
> this instance, all occurrences of a specified string with another
> specified string.

```html
string myString = "This is a car.";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myString);
sb.Replace(' a ', ' ');
```

[SOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.replace?view=net-5.0)